# BigQuery, how to use alias in where clause?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this small query, BigQuery don't recognise the alias maxdate, I am trying to return the table but only for that last date

```
WITH
  maxdate AS (
  SELECT
    MAX(DATE(SETTLEMENTDATE))
  FROM
    `biengine-252003.aemo2.daily`)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `biengine-252003.aemo2.daily`
WHERE
  DATE(SETTLEMENTDATE)= maxdate
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57862855/132438 for the updated question that asks about pruning partitions to get smaller scans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get the value of `maxdate` from your table `maxdate`. Add alias to your column and use this.

```
WITH
  maxdate AS (
  SELECT
    MAX(DATE(SETTLEMENTDATE)) as mx
  FROM
    `biengine-252003.aemo2.daily`)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `biengine-252003.aemo2.daily`
WHERE
  DATE(SETTLEMENTDATE) = (SELECT mx FROM maxdate LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to return the table but only for that last date

Meantime, more effective way to achieve the goal is

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(isLastDate) 
FROM (
  SELECT *, DATE(SETTLEMENTDATE) = MAX(DATE(SETTLEMENTDATE)) OVER() isLastDate
  FROM `biengine-252003.aemo2.daily`
)
WHERE isLastDate
```

Comment: strange SETTLEMENTDATE is a partition table, still BigQuery scan the whole table ?

Comment: your recent update changes your question quite a lot! if you have new question - you should post it as a new question! this gives you much better chance to get it answered and at the same time you respect efforts those who already answered your initial question :o)

Comment: will do, my apology

Comment: sure, no problem :o)

Comment: I add a separate question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57862114/bigquery-filter-per-the-last-date-and-use-partition

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like:

```
with maxdate as (
   select 
      max(date(SETTLEMENTDATE)) as mx
   from
  `biengine-252003.aemo2.daily`
)
select 
   d.* 
from `biengine-252003.aemo2.daily` d
left join maxdate on 1=1
where date(d.SETTLEMENTDATE) = maxdate.mx
```