# BigQuery filter per the last Date and use Partition

Tags: google-bigquery

I asked how to filter the last date and got excellent answers ([BigQuery, how to use alias in where clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57847205/bigquery-how-to-use-alias-in-where-clause)), they all work, but, they scan the whole table,  the field SETTLEMENTDATE is a partition field, is there a way to scan only one partition

as an example, I am using this query

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(isLastDate) 
FROM (
  SELECT *, DATE(SETTLEMENTDATE) = MAX(DATE(SETTLEMENTDATE)) OVER() isLastDate
  FROM `biengine-252003.aemo2.daily`
)
WHERE isLastDate
```

edit : please last date is not always current date, as there is lag in the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that [scripting is in beta](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) in BigQuery, you can declare a variable that contains the target date. Here's an example:

```sql
SET max_date DATE DEFAULT (SELECT DATE(MAX(datehour)) FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2019` WHERE wiki='es');

SELECT MAX(views)
FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2019` 
WHERE DATE(datehour) = max_date
AND wiki='es'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SETTLEMENTDATE is of DATE data type, you can use below to get today's partition

```
SELECT *
FROM `biengine-252003.aemo2.daily`
WHERE SETTLEMENTDATE = CURRENT_DATE()
```

or, for example for yesterday's partition

```
SELECT *
FROM `biengine-252003.aemo2.daily`
WHERE SETTLEMENTDATE = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

See more at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#querying_partitioned_tables_2

Comment: thanks, my data has lag, sometimes, it is late by 2 days, it meant max date is not always current date

Comment: what is the max delay possible? 2 days?, 3 days?

Comment: it is random, from today till 4 days

Comment: I was thinking about first select based on `WHERE SETTLEMENTDATE BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 4 DAY)  AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)` and then in outer query select based on max date in the result of that subquer. so you will be querying at most 4 partitions vs the whole table

Answer (score 1):

Mikhail's answer looks like this (working on public data):

```
SELECT MAX(views)
FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2019` 
WHERE DATE(datehour) = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)     
AND wiki='es' 
# 122.2 MB processed
```

But it seems the question wants something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(views)
FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2019` 
WHERE DATE(datehour) = (SELECT DATE(MAX(datehour)) FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2019` WHERE wiki='es')     
AND wiki='es'
# 50.6 GB processed
```

... but for way less than 50.6GB

What you need now is some sort of scripting, to perform this in 2 steps:

```
max_date = (SELECT DATE(MAX(datehour)) FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2019` WHERE wiki='es')   

;

SELECT MAX(views)
FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2019` 
WHERE DATE(datehour) = {{max_date}}
AND wiki='es'
# 115.2 MB processed
```

You will have to script this outside BigQuery - or wait for news on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36955074.